# How to find the longest repeated substring?

Tags: text-processing

Has anyone an idea how to solve the following on Ubuntu? I have a string in a text file. How can I find the longest substring *S* of it that *S* concatenated by itself is a substring on the original string?

For example, if an original string is `hfhfggccaggccagccafff`, the output should be `ggcca`. But what kind of program or script work if the original string is something like 700000 characters long?

My effort was a Python script

```
import re

s = 'hfhfggccaggccagccafff'
def find(s):
    r=max(re.findall(r'((\w+?)\2+)', s), key=lambda t: len(t[0]))

    return r

print(find(s))
```

Comment: This is something for code-golf SA ;-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Unix, but algorithms and programming

Comment: Can you give us some more details about what you are trying to do? You mention `ggcca`, are you working with DNA sequences? This really isn't something you would ever want to do in a language as slow and cumbersome as bash.

Comment: The obvious brute force search seems O(n^2), so you might want to see if there's a better algorithm for it, or at least some time-memory tradeoff you can use. Then it's just a question of programming, and you definitely don't do that in Bash, for various reasons, mostly because it would be horribly slow. There are actual programming languages for a purpose. cs.stackexchange or stackoverflow might be better places for this

Comment: @terdon This was an exercise from https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/tehtava.php?tunnus=mpera .

Comment: So you want us to just solve the entire exercise for you? In _bash_!? have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. I tried to write a Python script that uses regular expressions but it gave wrong answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
echo hfhfggccaggccagccafff |
grep -Po '(.*)\K\1' | awk 'length > l {l=length;s=$0} END{print s}'

ggcca
```

Of course, this won't do overlapping sequences.

Comment: It will think `hf` (instead of `fggcca`) is the longest repeated substring in `hfhfggccafggccagccafff`.

Comment: Did you test with the _modified_ string in my previous comment?

Comment: @Kusalananda duh, copy-and-paste error, sorry

Comment: @Kusalananda <quote>Of course, this won't do overlapping sequences</quote> And there are ways to do it much faster than with backreferences, but not in sed, perl, awk, grep, bash, etc.

Comment: @user414777, if you have a algorithm that would be faster than a brute force search, I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: @ilkkachu "brute force search"? are you trying to troll me? even a O(n) strstr(3) search for a substring you *already* know qualifies as "brute force search".

Comment: @user414777, sigh. no, I'm not trying to troll. It's just that you mentioned that better ways might be available, and I was interested in finding out what you had in mind.

Comment: @user414777 If brute force was the wrong phrase, then let's say better than a naive search instead. (The naive algorithm that comes to mind a somewhat obvious solution would be to start by looking at repeated substrings of lengths 1..n at position 1, then the same for position 2 etc. I don't what the regex engine would do in practice.) As for looking for a fixed substring, there's multiple algorithms for that, too. (Not that they could get rid of the O(n) factor for the searchable string length.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n -f <( awk '{ for (i = int(length/2) + 1; i > 0; --i) printf "s/.*\\(.\\{%d\\}\\)\\1.*/\\1/p;t\n", i }' file ) file
gccag
```

This uses `awk` to generate a number of `sed` statements.  Each statement tries to match find a repeated substring of a particular length, and terminates the `sed` script if it does so (by branching to the end of the script with `t` if a substitution is made by the preceding `s///` command).

For the given data, the following `sed` script is generated:

```sed
s/.*\(.\{11\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{10\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{9\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{8\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{7\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{6\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{5\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{4\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{3\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{2\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
s/.*\(.\{1\}\)\1.*/\1/p;t
```

The lengths of repeats are tested in decreasing order until a match is found.

I have not tested this on very long lines, but I note that the input to `sed` (and `grep`) is limited to "text files", and that a "text file" is a file whose lines are at most `LINE_MAX` characters, which POSIX defines as "at least" 2048 (which is also its actual value on Ubuntu). Also, there are limits to the number used in the `\{n\}` modifier.